# Problemas con password_verify

Tags: php

Tengo un problema con el `password_verify`, ya que cuando intento ingresar me muestra que la contraseña en incorrecto, intente lo mismo con *sha1* y es igual.

El registro:

```
if(count($errors) == 0) *[Aquí empieza el registro, que si no hay ningun problema pueda comenzar el registro]*{ 
    $response = file_get_contents("https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify?secret=$secret&response=$captcha");
    $arr = json_decode($response, TRUE);
    if($arr['success']) *[Esta parte verifica el captcha para poder continuar]*{
        $password_hash = hashPassword($Password); [Aquí llama a la función hashPassword (La pondre debajo)]
        $register = registerUser($User, $password_hash, $Email, $active, $user_type);   [Y registra el usuario (Pondre el codigo de registerUser debajo)]       
        if($register > 1){                  
            echo "DONE";
        } else {
            $error[] = "Wrong Captcha";
        }
    } else {
        $errors[] = "Error to register";
    }
}
```

El registro total: (Intente cambiar global $mysqli y tengo error)

```
function registerUser($User, $password_hash, $Email, $active, $user_type){ 
    global $mysqli;
    $stmt = $mysqli->prepare("INSERT INTO users (User, Password, Email, active, id_type) VALUES(?,?,?,?,?)");
    $stmt->bind_param('ssssi', $User, $password_hash, $Email, $active, $user_type);
    if ($stmt->execute()){
        return $mysqli->insert_id;
    } else {
        return 0;
    }
}
```

El usuario se registra bien y con la contraseña encriptada

Cuando intento logear me dice *contraseña incorrecta*:

```
function login($User, $Password, **[Intente poner $mysqli pero tengo error]**){
    global $mysqli;
    $stmt = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT id, id_type, Password FROM users WHERE User = ? || Email = ? LIMIT 1");
    $stmt->bind_param("ss", $User, $User);
    $stmt->execute();
    $stmt->store_result();
    $rows = $stmt->num_rows;

    if($rows > 0) {
        if(isActive($User)){
            $stmt->bind_result($id, $id_type, $Password);
            $stmt->fetch();
            $validatePassword = password_verify($Password, $Password); [He cambiando a $Password, $hash, $password_hash pero no he podido ingresar]

            if($validatePassword){
                lastSession($id);
                $_SESSION['id_User'] = $id;
                $_SESSION['user_type'] = $id_type;
                header("location: cpanel.php");
            } else {
                $errors = "La contrase&ntilde;a es incorrecta";
            }
        } else {
            $errors = 'El usuario no esta activo';
        }
    } else {
        $errors = "El nombre de usuario o correo electr&oacute;nico no existe";
    }
    return $errors;
}
```

He buscado en todos lados intente modificar pero no ha dado caso, agregué a mi base de datos un usuario con contraseña numérica para chequear y aún sigue así, creo que el problema esta en el login o en una parte de register.

***Agregado:*** La opción de password tiene un varchar(250) y lo he aumentado a 1000 para probar pero nada. Tengo la ultima versión de PHP también

Comment: El planteamiento de tu pregunta es confuso. No tiene sentido alterar el código para poner comentarios de cada cosa. Eso no sería necesario si plantearas la pregunta con claridad. No se entiende exactamente cuál es el problema. ¿Imprimiste las variables para revisarlas? ¿Probaste la consulta directamente en el manejador? Ese tipo de información es importante para resolver situaciones como esta.

Comment: El problema en si, es que, cuando intento ingresar con mi usuario creado, veo el error que la contraseña no es correcta, lo cual esta mal ya que esa es la contraseña, intente creando varios usuarios, pero aún así el error sigue, intente modificar el código para ver si el problema era en password_verify, pero aún sigue. Puse comentarios, porque la ultima vez que pregunte me preguntaron de que era cada código cuando yo lo había puesto.

Comment: ¿Imprimiste las variables para revisarlas? ¿Probaste la consulta directamente en el manejador?

Comment: lograste solucionar éste tema?

Answer (score 2):

para encriptar:

```
$hashgenerado = password_hash($clavedelusuario, PASSWORD_DEFAULT);
```

(supongo que a $hashgenerado la guardaras en una tabla o algo)

para verificar cuando entra el us.:

```
if password_verify($clavedelusuario, $hashgenerado) => ok.
```

Answer (score -1):

Asumiendo que tu función hashPassword usa de manera correcta password_hash de php (no aparece el código),
puedes probar lo siguiente:

En el bind_result debes cambiar el nombre de la tercera variable para que no pierdas *(no sobreescribir)* el $Password que recibes como parámetro para validar..

```php
...
$stmt->bind_result($id, $id_type, $PasswordHashInDB);
$stmt->fetch();
$validatePassword = password_verify($Password, $PasswordHashInDB);
...
```

Comment: prueba la modificación sugerida y me comentas. Suerte!

Comment: Revisar [answers]. Aclaraciones sobre la pregunta se realizan en los comentarios.